# Maximum acceleration of mass which is attached to a spring and is accelerated along friction less floor with acceleration a

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, spring

[image]

I just can't stop thinking about this .The answer is 2a But How??

Comment: Have you tried writing differential equations for the position of the mass and the position of the pulled end of the spring, and solving them to find exactly how the mass moves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a coordinate system accelerating with the front of the spring, the mass starts with an acceleration of: -a. It reaches the “equilibrium position” where is acceleration is zero (relative to the front of the spring), and the spring is stretched a distance, x. It passes through equilibrium and reaches a stretch of, 2x, where its acceleration is, +a. Combine this with the acceleration of the moving system and you get an acceleration of, 2a, in the fixed system. (You can think of the accelerating system as introducing a pseudo force which acts like gravity and gives a system hanging vertically.)